# Deduct values of two tables from each other and multiply result

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to deduct InclusiveTax from SellingPrice to get a new value in NETSellingPrice. And then multiply NETSellingprice by QTY to get NETValue.
Heres what i have and results.
Please assist.

select

```
ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.InternalMenuLinkItemNumber,ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.SiteNumber,ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.OrderMode,ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.InclusiveTax,ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.SellingPrice,COUNT(ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.InternalMenuLinkItemNumber) AS QTY
from ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed
where BusinessDate between '2017-06-27 00:00:00.000' and '2017-07-03 00:00:00.000' and
      SiteNumber='1001006' and 
      InternalMenuLinkItemNumber='1003471' and 
      ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.OrderMode='2'
group by ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.InternalMenuLinkItemNumber,ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.SiteNumber,ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.OrderMode,ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.SellingPrice,ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.InclusiveTax
```

**Result so far:**

```
InternalMenuLinkItemNumber|1003471
SiteNumber|1001006
OrderMode|2
InclusiveTax|1.830
SellingPrice|14.900
QTY|28
```

**What I`m looking for:**

```
InternalMenuLinkItemNumber| 1003471
SiteNumber| 1001006
OrderMode| 2
InclusiveTax| 1.830
SellingPrice| 14.900
QTY| 28
NETSellingPrice| ???
NETValue| ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code on top of your select query.

```
    Select *,
            (SellingPrice-InclusiveTax) NETSellingPrice,
            (SellingPrice-InclusiveTax)*QTY NETValue 
from (
      your select Statement
     ) A
```